# How to make 2 side by side columns look distinct from each other?

Tags: mobile, information-architecture, readability

I have a price chart like below. The 'buy price' is a listing on its own.. and 'sell price' is a listing on its own too. It just happens that they are placed side by side. E.g. The buy price is not related to the sell price in the same row.

My problem is how do I make it distinct that they are separate columns that are not directly related? But at the same time, they need to be both seen at one glance by the user for comparison/reference.

I was thinking of putting each of them in their own tabs but as per client requirement, that isn't an option.

Do note that **this is going to be on a mobile device** so I don't have much horizontal space to play around with.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Don't put them side-to-side if you don't want them too seem related.
[image]

edit: When targeting mobile, I would should them on top of each other, since the information is not connected. Otherwise your text will be too small to read comfortably:
[image]

Comment: That would work in desktop but in mobile there's not much space.

Comment: In mobile you should break it and show them on top of each other. Wasn't your goal to no have them be related? You didn't explain why they have to be side-by-side.

Answer (score 0):

Try to fine tune spaces between to make it more distinguished.
More space between not related content and less space between related content.
Also if scrolling is not an issue content might goes off the screen but just keep small clue that is something is outside
[image]